# Alert Postfix sender when outbound email is not delivered due to amavisd-new checks

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, clamav

I'm running Postfix 2.11 together with amavisd-new which works fine with spamassassin and clamav to prevent inbound/outbound spam and virus traffic.

Right now i'm looking for a way to alert users when outbound email is not delivered - rejected, quarantined, etc. Does anyone knows how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advaned!

Answer (score 1):

In amavisd.conf you'll have a few options that can be useful.

The options are :

```
$final_virus_destiny =
$final_banned_destiny =
$final_bad_header_destiny =

$virus_quarantine_to = 
$banned_quarantine_to = 
$bad_header_quarantine_to =
```

With the `$final_X_destiny` if you set it to D_BOUNCE, amavisd will create a DSN to the sender, this can be problematic if you're being spammed with spoofed addresses, you might want to look into creating a policy bank for authenticated users, and using this option just there.

The other option you have is the `$X_quarantine_to` if you set that to a particular email, you could run a script that checks the mailbox, and sends messages to people..

This [page](http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/amavisd-settings.html) has some further info also, including the spam counterparts to these options.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. Is it possible to create a different policy for inbound and for outbound email? Inbound email i would like to send it to iser's spam folder but outgoing email i would like to reject so the user can get same feedback as Postfix rejection policies.

Comment: Yeah, this article is a quite detailed explanation on setting up a policy bank for differentiating clients.. : http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/bypassing.html

Comment: For example, if your clients use the submission port (587) to send mail using TLS, you can set up a policy bank on all mail that arrives through 587, and direct it into amavis, using a custom policy bank..

Comment: Thank you so much, will give it all a read and post the results ASAP. Thanks again!